# python silently transposing rank 1 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix-multiplication

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
print("x1\n",x1,"\n")
x2 = np.arange(3.0)
print("x2\n",x2)
print(x2.shape,"\n")
print("Here, the shape of x2 is 3 rows by 1 column ")
print("x1@x2\n",x1@x2)
print("")
print("x2@x1  should not be possible\n",x2@x1,"\n"*3)
```

gives

```
x1
 [[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]] 

x2
 [0. 1. 2.]
(3,) 

Here, the shape of x2 is 3 rows by 1 column 
x1@x2 =
 [ 5. 14. 23.]

x2@x1  should not be possible, BUT
 [15. 18. 21.]
```

Python3 seems to silently convert x2 into (1,3) array so it can be multiplied by x1. Or am I missing some syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrays are being [broadcasted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by Numpy.

To quote the broadcasting documentation:

> The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different
>   shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints,
>   the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they
>   have compatible shapes. Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing
>   array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python. It
>   does this without making needless copies of data and usually leads to
>   efficient algorithm implementations. There are, however, cases where
>   broadcasting is a bad idea because it leads to inefficient use of
>   memory that slows computation.

Add the following line to your code where you explicitly set the shape of `x2` to `(3,1)` and you will get an error as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
print(x1.shape) # new line added
print("x1\n",x1,"\n")
x2 = np.arange(3.0)
x2 = x2.reshape(3, 1) # new line added
print("x2\n",x2)
print(x2.shape,"\n")
print("Here, the shape of x2 is 3 rows by 1 column ")
print("x1@x2\n",x1@x2)
print("")
print("x2@x1  should not be possible\n",x2@x1,"\n"*3)
```

**Output**

```
(3, 3)
x1
 [[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]] 

x2
 [[0.]
 [1.]
 [2.]]
(3, 1) 

Here, the shape of x2 is 3 rows by 1 column 
x1@x2
 [[ 5.]
 [14.]
 [23.]]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c61849986c5c> in <module>
     12 print("x1@x2\n",x1@x2)
     13 print("")
---> 14 print("x2@x1  should not be possible\n",x2@x1,"\n"*3)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 1)
```

Comment: thank you Rahul. This clarifies a LOT of Deep Learning python code that always seemed sloppy and confusing to me.

Comment: @aquagremlin : Happy to help!

Comment: @aquagremlin Isn't x2 * x1 failing? If you comment out the x2 * x1 line, it works. I.e x1 * x2 works i..e (3, 3) * (3, 1) but it fails when x2 * x1 is tried i..e (3, 1) * (3, 3). As it should.

Comment: sorry my vision is blurred

Comment: happens to the best of us :)

Comment: still got downvoted by who? was this question REALLY that bad?

Comment: Wasn’t me for sure. No explanation for the downvote either.